# How do I recover parameters from ARIMA?

Tags: r, estimation, arima

Given a simulated time series

```
test.ar <- arima.sim(list(ar = c(0.8, -0.2)), n = 1000)
```

I hoped to estimate the coefficients (0.8 & -0.2) using

```
arima(test.ar, order=c(2,0,0))
```

However, I see nothing that looks like 0.8 or -0.2

How do I recover the constants (0.2, 0.6 &c) from the following time series?

```
test.ma <- arima.sim(list(ma=0.2), n=1000)
test.arma <- arima.sim(list(ar=0.6, ma=0.2), n=1000)
```

Bonus:

```
tsts <- 5 + 0.5 * seq(1000) + arima.sim(list(ar = c(0.8, -0.2)), n = 1000)
```

Comment: If I `set.seed(1)` before running your first two code lines, I see parameter estimates of 0.76 and -0.22, which seems to be close enough to 0.8 and -0.2, given sampling variability. `auto.arima(tsts)` fits a simple trend model with no ARMA dynamics, which appears reasonable once you compare the strength of the trend signal to the ARMA signal (e.g., by plotting). I think I'm not fully understanding your question. Could you please elaborate? (Best to use `set.seed()` so we all talk about the same data.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa: I guess I am confused by the `intercept`; I also expected better estimates. I also don't see why `auto.arima(diff(tsts))` cannot recover anything useful. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I thought that `intercept` should be 0, and I see that it is smaller than it's `s.e.` (standard error), so how do I tell `arima` to fit a model without an intercept?

Comment: Here is the part of my earlier comment that is (still) valid: Better estimates: yes, time series are hard to reconstruct. We have had at least one previous question where the OP simulated a series and was surprised that auto.arima() fitted a completely different ARIMA model, though I can't find the question any more.

Comment: You can force `arima()` *not* to include an intercept by setting `include.mean=FALSE`.